# How can I fetch records from mysql table in cakephp 3.0 with OR condition?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I want to fetch records from table for names starting with a, b or c but with status=pending in cakephp 3.0. I am trying below query. Please check what is wrong with it as it is also fetching results starting with name 's':

```
$this->loadModel('DbArtists');
/*** fetching records alphabetically ***/
$artists_q = $this->DbArtists->find()->where(['album_status' => 'pending'])->orWhere(['name ' => 'A%', 'name ' => 'B%', 'name' => 'C%']);
$artist = $artists_q->all();
echo "<pre>";print_r($artist);die;
```

Comment: how can we combine both conditions then : ->where(['album_status' => 'pending'])->orWhere(['name ' => 'A%', 'name ' => 'B%', 'name' => 'C%']);?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do like below:-

```
$artists_q = $this->DbArtists->find()->where([
    'album_status' => 'pending',
    'OR' => [['name LIKE' => 'A%'],['name LIKE' => 'B%'],['name LIKE' => 'C%']],
]);
```

Or you can chek once this too:-

```
$query = $articles->find()->where(['album_status' => 'pending'])
->orWhere(['name LIKE' => 'A%'])
->orWhere(['name LIKE' => 'B%'])
->orWhere(['name LIKE' => 'C%']);
```

Reference:- https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html

Comment: @Gagzzz  glad to help you.:):)

Comment: you are genius :) :)